# Open Excel Document from Stream

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010

I am getting my excel docs as a byte[] (blobs) and rather than write it out to disk, then open it I was looking for a way to open straight from the stream. Googling brought me several results like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478410(v=office.14).aspx which is proper as we have office 2010 installed on target machines.

First thing I do is go to add a reference to DocumentFormat and it is not listed? Do I have to browse to the binary to add it?

But seriously Msoft only provides an open method that takes a string path?? I have got to be doing something wrong because it makes no sense that they would not have at LEAST an overload for a stream???

Here is my code and all I see is one Open option that takes a string path??

```
if(!initialized)
 Init();
workbooks =application.Workbooks;
workbook = workbooks.Open("string file path");
```

So really I am not interested in DocumentFormat unless I have to do it that way. What I want to do is open from stream without writing to disk...unless I really have to??

Comment: Office Interop is just a way to programmatically communicate with the Office applications... i.e. do via code what a user can do interactively... a user won't ever "open a stream"... which means you either save the `byte[]` to disk or open it with something else (not Excel)... to recommend anything you need to elaborate what exactly you want to do after opening the Excel file ?

Comment: Well the blob from the db is of course an excel file. I have a wrapper that will load the blob. The user will interact and most likely make changes. Then save where I was going to write the stream back to the db for storage in the blob.

Comment: Then you need to save the BLOB to disk...

Comment: @AndersGustafsson it doesn't since the OP wants to open the file in Excel itself for the user to interactively manipulate it...

Comment: @Yahia You are right, comment removed.